# Store details of Blobkey for images stored in google cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, blobstore, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to migrate an application from the google app engine standard environment first generation(python 2.7 runtimes) to second-generation ( python 3 runtimes).

The application serves the user-specific images stored in google cloud storage(previously blob storage). I have completed most of the migration as mentioned in the migration guide provided by Google.

I am facing the following challenges:

1. I am not able to find any specific way of creating `blob key` for blobs stored in google cloud storage. In the previous generation, I could use `create_gs_key` but that functionality seems removed.
2. Old application has stored image detail in the form of  `ndb.BlobKeyProperty()` how I can migrate these to cloud storage and retain the information. For the previous generation, I could use the `GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient` library.

Current stack:

- google app engine : python 3 runtime, flask HTML, jquery, javascript

Old stack:

- google app engine : python 2.7 runtime, webapp2, HTML, jquery, javascript

Disclaimer:

- Google does provide the option to use app engine APIs in python 3 runtimes by enabling `appengine apis` in app.yaml but it seems this functionality might be removed at any time.
- I do not want to keep the application permanently on python 2.7 using docker.
- Apart from `images API`,  I am not using any other legacy google app engine service.

> I might have missed something so feel free to correct me.

***EDIT 1:***

1. As mentioned, I have an old application that has `blob_key` indicating the blob key for stored images, if in the current version I have to use the `file name` directly I will have to either migrate the images stored in the form of blob key to google cloud storage, make changes to the model( I am trying to avoid this unless and until I don't have any other option)
2. If I understand correctly, `google.appengine.api.blobstore.blobstore`  is deprecated and using `blob store` methods is discouraged(Correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: I haven't seen any mention of blob keys for google cloud storage. Reading of data seems to be using the filename - https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_to_filename

Comment: The blob key (and `create_gs_key`) are part of the GAE Blobstore API, which is also available for [Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/services/bundled/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore).

Comment: Yes, i know that. I was saying that for reading directly from gcs (not via Blobstore), I have not seen any mention of blob keys so maybe you don't have to care about storing the blob key if you're going to be reading directly from gcs. Have you tried using the file name to read your file directly from gcs?

Answer (score 0):

I've been through almost the same problem: My GAE app was written with python2.7 and the API for that which was deprecated. What I did was create a completely new app with python3 and Flask, giving it the public api endpoint `api.{{my domain}}.com`. When a request comes for the images of an item, I invoke the legacy python2.7 version of my app and write it back to the new one. It isn't elegant but it was the best that I could do.

```
item = get_item(item_id)    
q = Image.query()
data = q.filter(Image.reference == item.key)
data = data.fetch(5)

for i in data:  
    # get the image from legacy and write it to new
    x_list = reqs.get(f"https://legacy.myapp.com/imgs/{item_id}").content
    l_json = json.loads(x_list)
    item.images = []
    for img_url in l_json.get("imgs"):
        img_data = reqs.get(img_url).content
        identity = str(uuid.uuid4())
        try:
            io_img_data = io.BytesIO(img_data)
            upload_blob("mynew_app.appspot.com", io_img_data, identity)
```